# Large deviations for finite state Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains, large-deviation-theory

There are many results for finite Markov chains ,e.g. Demob "Large deviations: Technique and its applications".

However I cannot find examples even for irreducible Markov chains, except for i.i.d. sequence such as binormial distribution.

Could you please give me some examples and the form of its rate functions?